# Removing Escape Characters from Marshalled Struct Golang

Tags: json, go, encoding, marshalling

The format of my JSON output after I marshal a struct has a lot of escape characters and double quotes.

I've tried using an encoder, Marshalling, RawMessages, forcefully removing parts of the string.

```golang
data := ChannelData{}
if err := rows.Scan(&data.Idx, &data.MciIdx, &data.Channel, &data.MatchIdx, &data.MatchCx, &data.StartTs, &data.EndTs, &data.Len, &data.MatchStartTs, &data.MatchEndTs, &data.MatchLen, &data.Happened, &data.Instance); err != nil {
log.Printf("%+v\n", rows)
log.Error().Err(err).Msg("unable to scan mysql data into struct")
continue
}

jsonD, err := json.Marshal(&data)
if err != nil {
log.Error().Err(err).Msg("cannot marshal data")
}
log.Debug().Msg(string(jsonD))

type ChannelData struct {
    Idx          string `json:"idx,string"`
    MciIdx       string `json:"mci_idx,string"`
    Channel      string `json:"channel,string"`
    MatchIdx     string `json:"match_idx,string"`
    MatchCx      string `json:"match_cx,string"`
    StartTs      string `json:"start_ts,string"`
    EndTs        string `json:"end_ts,string"`
    Len          string `json:"len,string"`
    MatchStartTs string `json:"match_start_ts,string"`
    MatchEndTs   string `json:"match_end_ts,string"`
    MatchLen     string `json:"match_len,string"`
    Happened     string `json:"happened,string"`
    Instance     string `json:"instance,string"`
}
```

I am getting:

{"level":"debug","time":"2019-07-10T20:12:09Z","message":"{\"idx\":\"\\"8931741865\\"\",\"mci_idx\":\"\\"107265043\\"\",\"channel\":\"\\"WPVIDT\\"\",\"match_idx\":\"\\"36028797060807935\\"\",\"match_cx\":\"\\"\\"\",\"start_ts\":\"\\"2019-07-10 17:57:59\\"\",\"end_ts\":\"\\"2019-07-10 17:58:14\\"\",\"len\":\"\\"00:00:15\\"\",\"match_start_ts\":\"\\"2019-06-05 07:14:52\\"\",\"match_end_ts\":\"\\"2019-06-05 07:15:08\\"\",\"match_len\":\"\\"00:00:16\\"\",\"happened\":\"\\"2019-07-10 17:58:16\\"\",\"instance\":\"\\"172.17.65.80\\"\"}"}

I expect it to be in JSON format:

{"level":"debug","time":"2019-07-10T20:12:09Z","message":"{"idx":"8931741865","mci_idx":"107265043","channel":"WPVIDT"...}"}

Comment: Remove all the `,string`s from your struct tags.

Answer (score 2):

For removing double quotes you could use `strconc.Unquote`

It would be great to see an example of a row of data to see if anything else is missing.

But from what is available here, if there is quotes in the string `json.Marshal` will not automagically remove them. You can remove quotes using the above command.

[Look at This Example](https://play.golang.org/p/id4f4r9tEr) for `Unquote`.

You can probably just write one method on the `ChannelData` struct that will unquote each field.

```
func (c *ChannelData) unquote() {
  c.Idx = strconv.Unquote(c.Idx)
.
.
.
}
```